# How to organise methods in a self join model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In designing a data model, you will sometimes find a model that should have a relation to itself. [Ruby On Rails Guide provides a neat example](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins). I am using it as a template for my example

For example, you may want to store all `users` in a single database model, but be able to trace relationships such as between `affiliate` and `users`. This situation can be modeled with self-joining associations:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :users, :through => :referrals
    has_one :affiliate, :through => :referral
end
```

This allows me to keep both `users` and `affiliate` in a same database table which is correct because fundamentally they are all individual users.

Problem arises when the model grows. `Affiliate` has its own set of methods - `earnings`, `expected_earnings` etc. These methods are very specific to `Affiliate` and I have my qualm keeping them with other `user` methods.

Loading object in correctly named variable helps:

```
affiliate = User.find 1
affiliate.earnings # used in context of affiliate

user = User.find 1
user.subscriptions # mostly in context to user
```

But when I read the `User` model, `Affiliate` related methods feels out-of-place.

Is there a way to namespace these methods correctly? What is the standard way of organizing self join model methods?

Comment: You could define a module, `AffiliatedUser`, which provide a set of methods. But you would have to make sure the methods are not overwriting other methods though...

Comment: consider using polymorphism (with additional model e.g. type)

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is with [Single Table Inheritance](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#single-table-inheritance).  Before accepting this approach, I would recommend searching the web for "single table inheritance rails" and reading up on the pros and cons of it.  A lot of digital ink has been spent on this subject.

With the caveat out of the way, Single Table Inheritance (STI) allows you to let multiple Rails models share one database table.  You do this by adding a `string` field called `type` to your database table.  Rails will interpret this as the subclass of your model.  You would then create several models that inherit from `User`.

In your specific case, the `type` field would either contain `user` or `affiliate`.  You would also create an `Affliliate` class which inherits from `User`.  All of your `Affiliate` specific methods would be put in the `Affiliate` class.  Rails is smart enough to use the `type` field in the database to identify records from the appropriate class.

Here is the migration you would run:

```
class AddTypeToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :users, :type, :string
    add_index  :users, :type
  end
end
```

Next you would add an Affiliate class:

```
# app/models/affliliate.rb
class Affiliate < User
   # Affiliate specific methods here.
end
```

You may also want to create a class for non-affiliate users.  Call it customers:

```
# app/models/customer.rb
class Customer < User
   # Customer specific methods here.
end
```

Use the appropriate class name when creating new records and rails will automatically populate the `type` field in the database.

You would then moving your associations to the appropriate model:

```
# app/models/affiliate.rb
class Affiliate < User
    has_many :customers, through: :referrals, foreign_key: :user_id
end

# app/models/customer.rb
class Customer < User
    has_one :affiliate, through: :referral, foreign_key: :user_id
end
```

I have not tested this, but it should work.

Comment: i went through your answer cursorily and it seems like a cleaner option. Let me test this out and research single table inheritance and will update you accordingly.